# $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure of the subring generated by an algebraic number

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be algebraic numbers which are not necessarily algebraic integers. Is there some invariant that allows us to determine whether $\mathbb Z[a]$ and $\mathbb Z[b]$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$-modules?

---

*Initial version of the question:* Let $a$ be an algebraic number which is not necessarily an algebraic integer. What is the $\mathbb Z$-module structure of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$?

Comment: It's not clear for me why the question was closed: the additive group structure of the ring generated by an algebraic number sounds a reasonable question. If the integral minimal polynomial is $P=a_nX^n+\dots+a_0$ with $\gcd(a_0,\dots,a_n)=1$, then clearly we obtain a group isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}[1/a_n]^n$ of $\mathbf{Q}$-rank $n$. If $n=1$, say $P=bX-a$ this is exactly $\mathbf{Z}[1/b]$. But even $n=2$ is worth looking. For $p$ prime, $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2$ admits uncountably many non-isomorphic subgroups.

Comment: So, let's say that $P=2X^2+bX+c$. If $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}_2$, then it's easy to check we obtain a group isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]^2$. But let's take $P(X)=2X^2+X+5$. It's split in $\mathbf{Q}_2$, with exactly one root in $\mathbf{Z}_2$. So in this case $A=\mathbf{Z}[t]$ is additively isomorphic to the kernel of some additive homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2\to C_{p^\infty}:=\mathbf{Z}[1/p]/\mathbf{Z}$, and also lies in a short exact sequence $0\to \mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2\to A\to C_{p^\infty}\to 0$.

Comment: So people who downvoted/closed should clarify why.

Comment: One useful invariant of the underlying abelian group of $\mathbf{Z}[a]$ will be the ring of endomorphisms of the underlying abelian group, which contains $\mathbf{Z}[a]$ as a subring. In some cases it will be the whole matrix group $M_n(\mathbf{Z}[1/k])$, but in some others it might remember $\mathbf{Z}[a]$.

Comment: @Ycor: I would guess many of them, like me, computed fairly quickly the structure of the tensor product with $\mathbb Z_p$ for each $p$ and assumed this more-or-less fixed the structure, forgetting the huge gulf you note between the purely $p$-local information contained in a $\mathbb Z$-module and the information that can be recovered after tensoring with $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Even the special case that  $a$ is the reciprocal of an algebraic integer is interesting. Suppose $a = b^{-1}$ where $b$ has irreducible polynomial $f$ (these types of things arise in stationary dimension groups). Then a prime $p$ is invertible in $G:= {\mathbf Z}[a]$ iff  all the non-leading coefficients are divisible by $p$. And  $G$ is strongly indecomposable (as an abelian group) and its endomorphism ring (as an abelian group) is commutative under some circumstances, e.g., if all the non-leading coefficients are relatively prime to the determinant.

Comment: Just to summarize the "local" information more explicitly, it gives the following first invariant of the additive group of $A=\mathbf{Z}[a]$: the degree $u(a)$, which is the $\mathbf{Q}$-rank of $A$, and for each prime $p$ the number $u_p(a)\in\{0,\dots,u(a)\}$ of roots of the minimal polynomial $P_a$ of $a$ that have $p$-adic norm $>1$ (it is 0 for $p$ large enough). Then $\mathbf{Z}[a]$ can be embedded as a discrete cocompact subgroup in $\mathbf{R}^{u(a)}\times\prod_p\mathbf{Q}_p^{u_p(a)}$. In my above example where $P_a=2X^2+X+5$, $u(a)=2$, $u_2(a)=1$ and $u_p(a)=0$ for odd $p$.

Comment: "but in some others it might remember ${\bf Z}[a]$." @YCor, what was this meant to say?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant "remember the ring $\mathbf{Z}[a]$" (up to isomorphism); it's deliberately vague because I was (and am still) unsure, expecting that in some cases the ring $A$ of endomorphisms of the additive group would be reduced to $\mathbf{Z}[a]$. Or not much bigger. For instance, if $A$ is reduced to $\mathbf{Z}[a]$, then the minimal polynomial over $\mathbf{Z}$ of $a$ is determined by the additive group structure modulo multiplication by an invertible element of this ring.

Comment: @YCor, OK, but what does it mean for a ring to "remember" another ring? I have never seen "remember" used as a technical term in Mathematics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes because it's not a technical term, it's a bit informal. Example "the group structure of the ring $\mathbf{Z}[1/n]$ remembers the set of prime divisors of $n$, but does not remember $n$ (does not distinguish $n=2$ and $n=4$". Whenever from a mathematical object $X$ you define another object $F(X)$ (an "invariant" of $X$), you can wonder how $F(X)$ "remembers" $X$. I found a few others examples with Google, e.g. about how the von Neumann algebra $L\Gamma$ of a group $\Gamma$ "remembers" $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 10):

Let $a$ be  an algebraic number, $K = \mathbb Q(a)$ the associated number field, $\mathcal O_K$ its ring of integers. Then the ring $\mathcal O_K[a]$ depends only on the set of places of $K$ at which $a$ is not integral.

$\mathcal O_K[a]$ is a good place to start for studying $\mathbb Z[a]$ because $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a finite index submodule of $\mathcal O_K[a]$. In particular, if $a \in \mathcal O_K$ then $\mathcal O_K[a]=\mathcal O_K$ is a finite free $\mathbb Z$-module, and hence $\mathbb Z[a]$ is as well, and the problem is trivial.

To say a little more about the structure of $\mathcal O_K[a]$, the key fact is that as a ring, it is $\mathcal O_K$ with some number of primes inverted. Hence as a $\mathbb Z$-module it is an extension of a sum of modules isomorphic to $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ by the finite free $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathcal O_K$. Specifically, the multiplicity of $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ is the total degree times ramification index of the primes lying over $p$ at which $a$ is not integral. Because $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a finite-index submodule of this, it is easy to see that it can also be expressed as a similar extension.

This should be enough information about the $\mathbb Z$-module structure for most practical purposes in number theory. However, as YCor points out, knowing the rank of $\mathcal O_K$ and the multiplicity of $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ does not come close to uniquely determining $\mathcal O_K[a]$ or $\mathbb Z[a]$, except in some special cases. In particular, he raises the question of determining when $\mathbb Z[a]$ and $\mathbb Z[b]$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$-modules.

---

Generalizing the case where $a$ is integral, there is one case where the problem simplifies considerably. Suppose there is some proper subfield $L$ of $K$ and ring extension $\mathcal O_L'$ with  $\mathcal O_L \subseteq \mathcal O_L' \subseteq \mathcal O_L$ such that $\mathcal O_K[a]= \mathcal O_L' \otimes_{\mathcal O_L} \mathcal O_K$. Then $\mathcal O_K[a]$ is a locally free module over $\mathcal O_L'$ (because $\mathcal O_K$ is a locally free module over $\mathcal O_L$) and $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a finite index submodule of $\mathcal O_K[a]$. This is only a small amount of extra data beyond $\mathcal O_L[a]$ and it seems impossible to recover much about $a$ from this data.

Thus, let us focus on the case where there does not exist such a proper subfield $L$ and ring $\mathcal O_L'$. Then, following YCor's suggestion, we can show that the ring of $\mathbb Z$-module endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z[a]$ is $\mathbb Z[a]$. In particular, this implies that (in this case) $\mathbb Z[a]$ and $\mathbb Z[b]$ are only isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$-modules if they are already isomorphic as rings.

---

It suffices to show that the ring of $\mathbb Z$-module endomorphisms, tensored with $\mathbb Q$, is isomorphic to $K$. This is because the ring of endomorphisms would then be commutative, hence commute with $a$, hence consist of $\mathbb Z[a]$-module endomorphisms, which are clearly only $\mathbb Z[a]$.

Since $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z} Z[a]$ contains $K$ and is contained in $M_n(\mathbb Q)$, it is a semisimple algebra, so it must be a matrix algebra of rank $r$ over a division algebra of rank $d$ over some field $L$. The field $L$ commutes with $K$ and so is contained in $K$. The minimal faithful representation of such an algebra has dimension $r d^2$ over $L$, so the index of $L$ in $K$ is at most $rd^2$, and the maximal commutative subalgebra has dimension $rd$ over $L$, so the index is at least $rd^2$. Thus $d=1$ and the index of $L$ is $r$. Hence this algebra is the full centralizer of $L$ inside $M_n(\mathbb Q)$. In particular, if $L=K$ then the endomorphism algebra must be $K$, as desired, so it suffices to handle the case when $L$ is a proper subfield. To do this, we will show that the set of places of $K$ at which $a$ is not integral is the pullback of a set of places from $L$. Because $\mathcal O_K[a]$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_K$ with that set of places inverted, it is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_L$, with the corresponding set of places inverted, tensored over $\mathcal O_L$ with $\mathcal O_K$, contradicting the assumption on the nonexistence of $\mathcal O_L'$.

Choose a prime $p$ over which $a$ is not integral and tensor everything with $\mathbb Z_p$. The ring  $\mathcal O_K[a] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z_p$  is  isomrphic to a product of local rings at places of $\mathcal O_K$ where $a$ is integral and local fields at places of $\mathcal O_K$ where $a$ is not integral. its endomorphisms preserve the subspace of $p$-divisible elemnts, which is the product of the local fields at the $p$-divislbe places. The endomorphisms contain the centralizer of $L$, and the only way everything in the centralizer of $L$ can preserve a certain $\mathbb Q_p$-subspace is if it is the kernel of some element of $L \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q_p,$ i.e. a product of the local fields at the places lying over some set of places of $L$ over $p$. Hence the set of places (over $p$) of $\mathcal O_K$ at which $a$ is not integral is the inverse image of a set of places of $\mathcal O_L$, as desired.

Comment: Forgive my denseness, but why is it sufficient to show that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$, when tensored with $\mathbb{Q}$, is isomorphic to $K$? Is this linked to the condition in your second paragraph? I also don't really understand this condition. Is $L$ a subfield of $K$? Can't you always set $L = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{O}_L' = \mathbb{Z}[a]$?

Comment: @oxeimon The key is that it is isomorphic to a specific copy of $K$, embedded by the obvious scalar multiplication action. The only elements of $K$ acting by scalar multiplication on $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ that preserve $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ are themselves in $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ (look at wehre they send $1$.)

Comment: @oxeimon $\mathbb Z[\alpha] \times _{\mathbb Z} \mathcal O_K$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$. The condition forces $\mathcal O_L' \otimes_{\mathcal O_L} L = L$.

Comment: Okay so you want $\mathcal{O}_L'$ to be a subring of $L$ containing $\mathcal{O}_L$? I'm sorry, I still don't understand the purpose of the condition you stipulate in your second paragraph. Surely you need more conditions, like $L$ a proper subfield of $K$? (or else, if $a\in\mathcal{O}_K$, then you could take $L = K$, $\mathcal{O}_L' = \mathcal{O}_L$). Or, are you assuming that $a$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$? Also, in your second paragraph how do you deduce that $\mathcal{O}_K[a]$ is free over $\mathcal{O}_L'$? (Are rings of integers always free over smaller rings of integers?)

Comment: @oxeimon: Sorry, I wrote this very quickly as I had to leave. I will edit it shortly. I do want $\mathcal O_L'$ to be as you say, but the condition that it is contained in $L$ should be implied by the condition on the tensor product. Yes, I need $L$ proper. Still, the condition of the second paragraph always obtains when $a$ is integral as then one can take $L=\mathbb Q$, $\mathcal O_L'=\mathbb Z$. The problem is trivial when $a$ is integral. I should say locally free rather than free, and then it is true about rings of integers.